# How to parse time between timezones

Tags: javascript, timezone, dayjs

I have this function:

```
export const convertTimeByTimezones = ({
  deadlineDateTime,
}) => {
  const res = dayjs("2024-01-16T18:30")
    .tz('America/New-York')
    .tz('Europe/London')
    .format('h:mmA');
  return res; // 4:30PM
};
```

It should be 23:30

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the `tz` method second argument

```
  const res = dayjs
    .tz(deadlineDateTime, "America/New-York")
    .tz("Europe/London")
    .format('h:mmA');
  return res;
```